# If multiple condition occurs then fetch rows from table based on first one among them in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Table:

```
  Login
  [user_id,type]
    {1,5}
    {2,1}

    Personal
  [user_id,first_name,last_name,city_name]
    {1,x,y,ohio}
    {1,x,y,new_york}
    {2,p,q,new_york}

    Working
  [city_idcity_name]
    {1,ohio}
    {1,new_york}
```

SQL:

```
    select lgn.user_id, ps.first_name, ps.last_name, wrk.city_name
    from Login lgn, Personal ps, Working wrk
    where wrk.city_name = ps.city_name and ps.user_id = lgn.user_id and lgn.type = 5
```

Problem:

In the above table you can see a user "x" having two different address and my query is based on matching city_name with Working and Personal Tables,
still there are two addresses available so it should fetch details based first coming city_name
How can we do that in MYSQL..?
Help me with it..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Which one is first? Remember, rows in RDBMS have no inherent order.

Comment: Define "first" city... Alphabetically first? Lowest ID? Random?

Comment: @Strawberry I am not clear about inherent order can u just give a brief on it..please..

Comment: @Bohemian "first" in the sense, if there area multiple addresses then it should fetch the only one (probably the first row) and leaving the rest..

Comment: But which is the "first"? First as measured by what? In SQL databases, data has no natural order - it's effectively random, unless you impose order - so how would you order duplicate cities?

Comment: @Bohemian fine..take it in this way..
last recently added to the table

Comment: @VinodhVelumayil how can I know which was last added? There is no way to know given the columns listed in your question. Is there an auto incrementing "id" or a "timestamp" column somewhere?